# R: Data Cleaning

Tags: r

I hope someone can help me in cleaning my data using R.

Sample data:

```
seqno   rectyp  ps04
1       1   
1       1   
1       89  
1       89  
2       1       0
2       1       1
2       1   
2       90  
2       89  
3       1   
3       1   
3       1   
3       90  
3       90  
3       89      1
3       89      5
3       89      6
3       89
```

What I would like to do is look for values `ps04==1` and `rectype==1` for a certain `seqno` value. Once found, it will fill out the whole rows of that `seqno` with value `1`. Expected output would be:

```
seqno   rectyp  ps04
1       1   
1       1   
1       89  
1       89  
2       1       1
2       1       1
2       1       1
2       90      1
2       89      1
3       1   
3       1   
3       1   
3       90  
3       90  
3       89      1
3       89      5
3       89      6
3       89
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see what rows meet `t$ps04==1 & t$rectyp==1`. Get the `seqno` for those and then make `i` equal `TRUE` for all the rows that meet the condition.

```
> i <- t$seqno %in% t$seqno[t$ps04==1 & t$rectyp==1]
> i
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> t$ps04[i] <- 1 # set values to 1
> t
   seqno rectyp ps04
1      1      1   NA
2      1      1   NA
3      1     89   NA
4      1     89   NA
5      2      1    1
6      2      1    1
7      2      1    1
8      2     90    1
9      2     89    1
10     3      1   NA
11     3      1   NA
12     3      1   NA
13     3     90   NA
14     3     90   NA
15     3     89    1
16     3     89    5
17     3     89    6
18     3     89   NA
```

Comment: HiJulian, Thanks for your response!This is what i need.Thanks!